# How to assess effect of event within group

Tags: regression, repeated-measures, intervention-analysis

I'm trying to conduct an analysis for my organisation of a change in the our complaints processing system with regards to whether it has had any adverse impact relating to a couple of demographic variables (mainly gender and ethnicity as there is a lot of data missing for other variables).

In 2019 we went from one system to another. In the new system, all information coming into the organisation gets processed by a team that did not exist prior to 2019. The outcomes of interest are whether a complaint was progressed to another team, and whether a complaint was then progressed to disciplinary action (two separate analyses are need for each part of the complaints process).

With the new system, we now log far more complaints, with a smaller proportion getting progressed, meaning that inevitably there will be quite a big impact of the new system in any model looking at this. This makes looking at pre-and post intervention slightly meaningless for the population as a whole, but there may be some interesting trends seen within groups, and it is this that is of most interest.

I am trying to figure out what approach would be best to take with regards to testing whether the change in the system has had any adverse in group impacts. The data does not match up all that well between the two systems in terms of the information that complaints are tagged with, which leaves just a few variables possible to use, making it difficult to control for a lot of potential variance. There is also an issue that the same individual can be subject to multiple complaints (does this create an unbalanced panel?).

I have been looking into Interrupted Time Series Analysis, but this seems more appropriate for looking at things on a population level, and not within group differences. The same goes for Difference of Differences approaches.

- I wondered whether a basic logistic regression model with a before
  and after dummy variable interacted with the demographic variables of
  interest may be the way to go?  Would this approach make sense?
- How could I include as much of the data as possible, but also control for
  some individual appearing in the dataset more than once?
- Is there an approach in interrupted time series analysis, where I could run a segmented regression on different groups within the same population and then compare the results between the different groups? This seems like the simplest approach, but I haven't been able to find any literature on this, which makes me think that it probably isn't the way to go.
- What approach would be the best to take overall?

I feel like I'm on the way to creating a garbage in, garbage out model at the moment, particularly given the lack of useful variables to use, and not knowing the best approach to take. Any help would be much appreciated. I haven't done intervention analysis with such complicated data before and am a bit out of my depth.